# Using elements inside Vue object in external js file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

main.js:

```
new Vue({
  data: {
    globals: {
      notifications: [],
      dynamicTabs: {}
    }
  },
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

I can use this code block in my Vue components like this:

```
this.$root.globals.notifications = [{
 type: type,
 title: title,
 text: typeof text == 'String' ? this.$t(text) : this.$t(text[0], text[1]),
 autoDismiss: autoDismiss,
 dismissOnClick: dismissOnClick
}]
```

But I want to use the same in an external js file. I can't reach my global object with "this"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use $root.

For example:

**VUE 2 | Before new Vue:**

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: system.apiURL,
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  },
});

Vue.prototype.$system = system;

// prototype
Vue.prototype.$http = api;
Vue.prototype.$help = help;
```

**Use this:**

```
this.$http.post('/', ...);
```

**VUE 3 | After createApp**

```
const app = createApp(App);
// ...
app.config.globalProperties.$moment = moment;
app.config.globalProperties.$filters = {
  formatDate(value) {
    return moment(value);
  },
};
```

**Use this:**

```
this.$filters.formatDate(...)
```